# How can i change the expiry of Google Analytics.js from 12 hours?

Tags: google-analytics

Can you tell me how to increase the expiry time of the Google Analytics. All the page speed tests are telling me to increase it beyond 12 hours.

So far I have tried setting the expiry in the `.htaccess` file for all `*.js` files but it doesn't have any effect. I have also searched on the Analytics help pages and forum, without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download/host it yourself -- just make sure you follow the [Google Analytics ga.js Changelog](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/changelog#changelog) and update it when applicable.

Note: PageSpeed is a recommendation, not a 100% steadfast rule.  I'd be willing to bet you're over-optimizing something seemingly easy and could focus on other internal efforts for better performance gains.  Give [Yotta](http://www.yottaa.com/) a shot and see what they say/think.

Comment: Thats a fantastic suggestion Tom, thank you. According to GT Metrix the site was reading 98/100 for both Page Speed and YSlow..thought that was pretty impressive :o)

Comment: O.o sounds like you're doing fine!